# Win Phone 8 app and checking apps from same publisher installed on device

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

in the MSDN documentation it says that within an application you can check if an app has been installed from the same customer and launched from within another app. a part of the documentation from the following link below

[Launching, resuming, and multitasking for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/enus/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207014%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Launchingotherapps)

You can use APIs from the `Windows.Phone.Management.Deployment` namespace to see if other apps from your publisher ID are installed on a phone.

If they’re installed, you can also use this API to launch them. To demonstrate, the following example enumerates all apps for the current publisher ID and launches the first app in the enumeration (unless that app happens to be the current app).

```
IEnumerable<Package> apps = Windows.Phone.Management.Deployment.InstallationManager.FindPackagesForCurrentPublisher();
apps.First().Launch(string.Empty);
```

I want to check for the existence of an app on a device with a certain publisher id, without publishing the application or making a beta test as this takes time.

I can get the publisher ID from the company that are publishing the  the app (this is external to me). my question is, is there a way I could test this in real time while debugging my code. for example just changing my publisher id in the manifest?